# AWS S3: Get Server-side encryption settings using CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I can use the Amazon S3 web GUI console, click on a file on S3, and see the Server-side encryption settings, including which AWS KMS key is used.

How can I get this same information with the CLI? I've checked every obvious command and I'm finding nothing.

This shows me bucket level info, I want file level info:

```sh
aws s3api get-bucket-encryption
```

This doesn't show KMS/SSE info:

```sh
aws s3api get-object-acl
```

This just downloads the file, it doesn't get properties about the file:

```sh
aws s3api get-object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: You probably would want to use `aws s3api head-object`

> This just downloads the file, it doesn't get properties about the file: `aws s3api get-object`

I don't know what version of the AWS CLI are you using, but with the latest one if you run `get-object` like this:

```
aws s3api get-object --bucket <bucket-name> --key <keyname> <outfile>
```

It will download the file, but it will also display something like this:

```
{
    "AcceptRanges": "bytes",
    "LastModified": "2022-01-20T21:24:21+00:00",
    "ContentLength": 17851,
    "ETag": "\"4a57f3ee4dd576e295c8ff0c9ad86063\"",
    "ContentType": "image/jpeg",
    "ServerSideEncryption": "aws:kms",
    "Metadata": {},
    "SSEKMSKeyId": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:069700690668:key/b2ae18e5-13ce-466a-82aa-641eb817d063"
}
```

This should contain the encryption type (`ServerSideEncryption`) and the ARN of the KMS key used `SSEKMSKeyId`. You can see the docs for all the outputs for [`get-object`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/get-object.html).

Certainly, downloading the object is may be unnecessary in some cases. If you don't want to download the object, you may want to use [`head-object`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html):

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket <bucket-name> --key <keyname>
```

The output is the same as in case of `get-object`.